# Finding answers to my own OPs

Tags: discussion

While looking for articles on "antiset theory," I have found answers to both of the following questions, that I myself posted:

1. [Whether universal sets are contradictory (not for Russell/powerset reasons, though)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97578/would-a-universal-transet-violate-the-law-of-identity)?
2. [Whether there is a set theory involving abstract contingency](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97159/would-contingently-inhabited-sets-be-necessarily-impure)?

I don't mean to say that I found "conclusive" answers so much as well-citable ones. [The same essay](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=465d8f56b8d1d9035b397658ead1c734d98cf517) is in fact what answers both:

> Thus we can’t treat the antisets like common sets, but treat them as *sets of abstract space*, i.e., sets that have the **potential** to contain elements, but still has not! [bold-face emphasis added]

> Moreover, by definition of antisets arises naturally the concepts of antigroups and antirings. From there we show the impossibility of building antifields, giving us the impossibility to eventually build a possible *“Antimathematics”*.

The first quote corroborates the intuition I had on reading a different paper on antisets, viz. that antiset theory can be used to implement the idea of abstract contingently inhabited sets (I don't think the implementation option is stated in the other paper), albeit one might quibble that "potentially inhabited, but not yet inhabited" means something other than "possibly inhabited, but not actually inhabited." Anyway, the second quote corroborates the solution I came up with to a self-negating universe, viz. go right to a universal antiset and apply the union axiom to that and a universal positive set, but include so-called *mitigating elements* such that, when they coinhabit a set with otherwise opposed elements, they "neutralize" or "defuse" the conflict and preserve a nonempty union of the otherwise opposed elements (with their mitigator(s)). Not, then, that the paper here quoted speaks of mitigating elements in this regard (I haven't read the full text yet, but it might speak of these things), but still, if the bent of the paper is against the concepts of antifields or antiworlds (as such), it would seem to go to show that whatever process it is that represents a universal category/type/set/class/w/e, is one that limits the logical strength of the concept of negation, enough to where an "actively negative universe of mathematical discourse" is ruled out.

Should I use the linked essay to provide answers to my OP questions? (I also found an answer to my "is there a difference between intensional and extensional elementhood relations" OP, like I literally read some paper where they used the phrase "extensional element of" or something, but I had trouble backlogging it later, so I'd have to leave off on self-answering that one...) What guidelines are there on self-answering, here? I was actually confident enough in my assessment of some obscure issue in Kant exegesis to self-answer an OP of mine about the subject, but I don't know that this contributed much value to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and even encouraged to answer your own questions, provided you found an answer which suits the question. Even if it is a partial answer "only".

Mind, the system even got the possibility implemented to answer the question *while posing the question*.